# Embedding fonts

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP with an XML document, and I'm trying to render a pdf.  I have to embed a font into the resultant pdf file because it has to use international characters.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/stable/fonts.html should give you everything you need to do that.